# UVa 482 - Permutation Arrays Runtime Error, But Why?

Tags: java, regex, algorithm

My Java code execute completely,and the result is right. but UVa judged My code Runtime Error. I dont kown why and where is the error ?

MyCode :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] s1 = new String[100000];
        String[] s2 = new String[100000];
        String str1;
        String str2;
        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\S+");
        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("\\S+");
        int n;
            n = scan.nextInt();
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                int j = 0, l = 0;
                str1 = in.nextLine();
                str2 = in.nextLine();
                Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(str1);
                Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(str2);
                while(m1.find()) {
                    s1[j++] = m1.group();
                }
                while(m2.find()) {
                    s2[Integer.parseInt(s1[l++])-1] = m2.group();
                }
                if(i != 0)
                    System.out.println();
                for(int w=0; w<j; w++) {
                    System.out.println(s2[w]);
                }
            }
    }
}
```

UVa 482 - Permutation Arrays  :

In many computer problems, it is necessary to permute data arrays. That is, the data in an array must be re-arranged in some specified order. One way to permute arbitrary data arrays is to specify the permutations with an index array to point out the position of the elements in the new array. Let x be an array that is to be permuted and let x' be the permuted array. Then, we have the relationship between x and x' that  x'pi = xi.

Input
The input begins with a single positive integer on a line by itself indicating the number of the cases following, each of them as described below. This line is followed by a blank line, and there is also a blank line between two consecutive inputs. 
Each input set will contain two lines of numbers. The first line will be an index array p containing the integers 1...n, where n is the number of integers in the list. The numbers in the first line will have been permuted in some fashion. The second line will contain a list numbers in floating point format.

Output
For each test case, the output must follow the description below. The outputs of two consecutive cases will be separated by a blank line. 
The output for this program will be the list of floating point numbers from the input set, ordered according to the permutation array from the input file. The output numbers must be printed one per line in the same format in which they each appeared in the input file.

Sample Input

```
1
3 1 2
32.0 54.7 -2
```

Sample Output

```
54.7
-2
32.0
```

Comment: Unrelated, but why did you instantiate two `Scanner`(s)?

Comment: Bacause n = scan.NextInt();  str = scan.NextLine(); the str will contains enter key .  Instantiating  tow Scanner can solve the problem. Just like scanf("%d",&n); getchar();getLine(cin, str); you must add a statement " getchar();" in C++.

Comment: Why not just `scanner.nextInt()` and "forget" the fact that they are on different lines? The Scanner on default settings will just ignore all the whitespaces, since it is set as delimiter.

Comment: At the beginning, I used a scanner but the result is wrong.  Just like the code :

Comment: Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  //Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  String s1,s2,s3;
  int n;
  n = scan.nextInt();
  s1 = scan.nextLine();
  s2 = scan.nextLine();
  System.out.println(s1);
  System.out.println(s2);

Comment: result is not your input .  Besides can't input with the rules in code.

Comment: Oh, you don't know how many numbers there are on a line. You only need to read the file line by line, then for the other 2 lines, use `split` function and convert all elements in the first line into number. As for the problem you have `String s1,s2,s3; int n; n = scan.nextInt(); s1 = scan.nextLine(); s2 = scan.nextLine();` You need a call to `scan.nextLine()` after reading number of test cases, to consume the new line after the number of test cases.

Comment: Thank you. I have a try.

Comment: But I also want to know Why My code Runtime Error again?

Comment: @wxisme try to debug yourself by adding some log, there are many places can go wrong in your code, as this code is so input dependent. It is hard to tell without providing the specific input, and again, we need to debug it, so my best advice is try to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

> ... Runtime Error. I dont kown why and where is the error ?

You cannot reliably use two `Scanner`s in parallel on one `InputStream` (`System.in`), because [*more bytes may be read ahead from the underlying stream than are necessary to satisfy the current read operation.*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) The error is probably

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

because the

```
            n = scan.nextInt();
```

read ahead (and buffered) all the input so that for

```
                str1 = in.nextLine();
```

no input was left.
Since this behaviour is optional, your usage may work in your environment and fail in others.